# Breakpoint on the event java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, debugging, breakpoints, indexoutofboundsexception

How to add a breakpoint on the evenet `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

```
System.out.println(this.getItem(j+1).getUniqueId() + ", Service time: " + this.getItem(j+1).getServiceTime() + ", Arrival time: " + this.getArrivalTimes().get(j+1));
```

The problem is that either `this.getItem(j+1)` or `this.getArrivalTimes().get(j+1)` fails. However I checked that `j+1` does never exceed the list size. Therefore I want to add a beakpoint to see the reason. Without the breakpoint it is difficult to debug this line of code, because it is executed many times and debugger does not stop when the error occurs.

Comment: you can't add a breakpoint to the line just before this and inspect the content?  And remember, most things are 0 indexed, so you can only get up to length-1.

Comment: @MadConan If I add a brekpoint to the line before this, then I will need to inspect around 1000 executions of this line until this error message occurs.

Comment: You can always set hit condition to stop after 1000 hits...

Comment: Set a watch point like `j=container.length` assuming you can get the length of the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your IDE it should be possible to set an exception breakpoint. In Eclipse its a little icon in the breakpoint view that looks like a "J" wqith an exclamation mark. In Intellij you can edit breakpoints with "View Breakpoints", then add an exception breakpoints via the add breakpoint menu.

Answer (score 0):

> However I checked that j+1 does never exceed the list size

**It should never exceed collection's size - 1!** Collections in Java are 0 based, so last element's index will be `list.size()-1`

Comment: This line is inside the loop for (int j = 0; j < this.getItems().size()-1; j++) {... So, it never exceeds list.size()-1

Comment: But you are using index increment. Don't use `getItem(j+1)` only `getItem(j)` because on last iteration `j+1==list.size()` = IndexArrayOfBoundsException. Easy.

Comment: Last iteration is j < this.getItems().size()-1. So last j+1 == this.getItems().size()-1.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a breakpoint on the exception itself, you can break the statement to different lines to see where it happends. Or just set a conditional breakpoint to the line with the condition `collection.size < j`